# Unable to install any extension on Magento 2.1.0 website

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer, zend-framework

I have a site running on Magento 2.1.0.

The site was up and running for a few weeks with no issues, we were able to install a few extensions with no problems.

Suddenly, we are unable to install any extensions. When I run the command to enable any module, I get the following error:

```
[Zend_Json_Exception]          
Decoding failed: Syntax error  


My full trace is below:

Exception trace:
 () at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Json.php:97

 Zend_Json::decode() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:85

 Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->load() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/PackageInfo.php:208

 Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo->getRequire() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:132

Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->createGraph() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:95

 Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependencyGraph() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DependencyChecker.php:82

 Magento\Framework\Module\DependencyChecker->checkDependenciesWhenEnableModules() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Status.php:98

 Magento\Framework\Module\Status->checkConstraints() at /home/*/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AbstractModuleManageCommand.php:92

 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AbstractModuleManageCommand->execute() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257

 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96

 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /home/*/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/*/public_html/bin/magento:24

module:enable [-f|--force] [--all] [-c|--clear-static-content] [--magento-init-params="..."] [module1] ... [moduleN]
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I haven't seen that before, but there's most likely a syntax error in the composer.json file of one of your modules. I'd check each app/code/{vendor}/{module}/composer.json until you find the problem.